# Adding MultiplePricebooks to an Opportunity

Tags: opportunity-lineitem, product, pricebook

We have three different set of Prices for an Product . Lets say (Type A, Type B, Type C) and each type has three set of prices (List Price,Sales Price and Landing Price). We have a requirement to add Type A and Type B in a single Opportunity. I assume that I can create three set of Pricebooks for A,B and C. But how can I add Type A,Type B and C in a single opportunity and the team should be able to differentiate which type a product belongs to when the see the Opp Product Line Item .Can someone please advise.

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sales_admin_products_quotes_contracts/sales_admin_products_quotes_contracts_unit_1 is a good place to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, your requirement can't be done - an Opportunity may only have 1 Pricebook

You'll need to create different SKUs (ProductCodes) with different prices within a common Pricebook to achieve this; then use Product Family field to distinguish between types

Comment: This sounds like an Excellent Idea!! Thank you @cropredy..  I will try this